# "A BIRT exception occurred: Can not convert the value of Bruce to Double type.. See next exception for more information."

Tags: eclipse, birt, birt-emitter, birt-deapi

Hi I am trying to develop birt cross tab report, but i am getting below error. please give me some solution to solve this.

The following items have errors:

ReportDesign (id = 1): 
- A BIRT exception occurred: Can not convert the value of Bruce to Double type.. See next exception for more information.

Comment: i have data in string format only, but report is trying to convert t into double. I do not understand why its happening and how to resolve this.

Comment: Please help me..i am very tired by keep on trying to fix this.

Comment: what are your column type? how much column have you in Double type? What are they?

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace. Mention BIRT version, if you are using scripted data sets if you have debugging active and so on. Or just paste the complete XML